# how can i detect if there are different folders in the my game folder?

Tags: c#

string[] folderNames = new[]
{
"anim",
"audio",
"cleo",
"custom_models",
"data",
"libraries",
"models",
"modloader",
"movies",
"SAMP",
"text"
};

string gameFolder = oyunDizin;

```
        foreach (var folderName in folderNames)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(gameFolder + folderName))
            {


                MessageBox.Show(folderName + " İzinli");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(folderName + " İzinsiz");
 }


    }
```

I want detect if there are different folders in my gta san andreas folder? Granted folders in a folderNames but i want if i have not granted folder messagebox error.

Comment: please format all of your code, not just some of it

Comment: oyunDizin variable is my game folder brother, thank you for answer

Comment: that is not an answer ... it is a request

Comment: `oyunDizin variable is my game folder` ... that belongs in the question above ... it does not belong in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Directory.GetDirectories()` to scan existing folders in your root folder

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(gameFolder))
{
    if(!folderNames.Contains(Path.GetFileName(f)))
    {
        //show error
    }
}
```